# How to respond with a pdf for browser with idhttpserver?

Tags: delphi-7, indy

I' have a server application made in delphi7, i'm using idhttpserver and when a user of my website requests a report via GET passing parameters, i wish response to this client with a pdf  version of report, how could i do that?

Comment: Please include some code to show what you have tried.

Comment: I can't do it right now i'm out side home coming from my job, but the only thing that i did was receive parameters from webbrowser request latter i'm gonna post the code thank you

Comment: i got impressed cause i think i did a clear question, but some not answer and stil downvote, not every question needs a explicit code to example

Comment: It doesn't have to be code all the time, but it's a very nice way to see very quickly your own research effort and on SO a question usually "needs" code by convention (see http://stackoverflow.com/help for details).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to generate the PDF report yourself, that is outside of Indy's scope.  Just make sure you do it in a thread-safe manner, as `TIdHTTPServer` is a multi-threaded component that uses worker threads to process client requests.

In the `TIdHTTPServer.OnCommandGet` event, you can access the requested parameters via the `ARequestInfo.Params` property if `TIdHTTPServer.ParseParams` is true, otherwise you can manually parse the value of the `ARequestInfo.QueryParams` property.  To send the report back to the client, you can either:

1. save the report to a `.pdf` file and then call the `AResponseInfo.ServeFile()` method. For example:

   ```pascal
   procedure TForm1.IdHTTPServer1CommandGet(AContext: TIdContext;
     ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
   begin
      // handle request parameters...
      // generate PDF to file...
      AResponseInfo.ServeFile(AContext, 'C:\path to\report.pdf');
   end;
   ```
2. save the report to a `TStream` object, assign that to the `AResponseInfo.ContentStream` property (`TIdHTTPServer` will take ownership of it), and set the `AResponseInfo.ContentType` property to `'application/pdf'`. For example:

   ```pascal
   procedure TForm1.IdHTTPServer1CommandGet(AContext: TIdContext;
     ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
   begin
      // handle request parameters...
      AResponseInfo.ContentType := 'application/pdf';
      AResponseInfo.ContentStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
      // generate PDF into ContentStream...
   end;
   ```

Comment: Thanks you @Remy Lebeau , was exactly that i needed